# how to render html format in node.js (openweathermap.api)

Tags: node.js, express, pug, weather

This is my code below. What I want to do is when I render, I'd like to render a html format to index.pug without using res.send(body);
When I put a zipcode, a result like the below link will show under text in index.pug.

body is this link. this link is designed in html not image.

[link I want to use](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=html&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)

topic.js

```
 router.post('/weather', function(req,res){
      let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${req.body.zipcode}&mode=html&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`
      request(url, function (err, response, body) {
//this below code works but not what I wanna do           
res.send(body);
//this is something I'd like to use
res.render('index',text:body);
          }
       });
    })
```

index.pug

```
h1= text
```

Comment: I've been spending more than half of a day dealing with this problem... trying to become a programmer but guessing i'm far away yet.

Comment: take a look at promises, use them to request all your data and then at the end render your information

Comment: In my opinion promises are only going to add a layer of complexity that will confuse the OP.  I'd say focus on arrays.

Comment: each time I use request for each zipcode in zipcode_table, I assume to use request one out of time. is there any way to use multiple urls to receive more data regarding weather condition and temperature of  each zipcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue you're seeing is calling the OpenWeather API and fetching only one zip code at a time.  Let's fix that first, then we need to address getting the data efficiently into the pug template where you can generate your table.

*1. Fetching Multiple Values*

The [API spec](https://openweathermap.org/current) says that you can string multiple [city ID](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/)'s together but not zip codes.  If you want to keep this easy in the route you should switch to city ID:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric
```

Otherwise you will need to make multiple calls to the api in the route, something that is possible using a library such as [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) but you say you're just starting out with programming so that's probably not a good first step.

Hopefully your app can use City ID instead, or at the very least you can start with that.

*2. Sending the results to the template*

The results from a multi-city query look like [this](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22):

```
{"cnt":3,"list":[{"coord":{"lon":37.62,"lat":55.75},"sys":{"type":1,"id":7323,"message":0.0036,"country":"RU","sunrise":1485753940,"sunset":1485784855},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"main":{"temp":-10.5,"pressure":1028,"humidity":66,"temp_min":-11,"temp_max":-10},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5,"deg":200},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1485793175,"id":524901,"name":"Moscow"},{"coord":{"lon":30.52,"lat":50.45},"sys":{"type":1,"id":7358,"message":0.0268,"country":"UA","sunrise":1485754480,"sunset":1485787716},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"main":{"temp":-11.04,"pressure":1033,"humidity":61,"temp_min":-15,"temp_max":-9},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3,"deg":150},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1485793175,"id":703448,"name":"Kiev"},{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0034,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762036,"sunset":1485794875},"weather":[{"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"},{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"main":{"temp":7,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":5,"temp_max":8},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.6,"deg":90},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485793175,"id":2643743,"name":"London"}]}
```

You'll need to loop through every entity in the `list` property and extract the data you want.  Here's an example using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), it loops through the results, creates a new simpler object for each city, then adds that to the weatherData array.  Just pass weatherData into your template using res.render and you'll find it very easy to create your table.

```
var weatherData = [];

for(var city in body.list){
  var cityWeather = {
    "name": city.name,
    "temperature": city.main.temp,
    "weather": city.weather[0].description
  };

  weatherData.push(cityWeather);

}

res.render('topic/weather', {"cities": weatherData});
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanations!!! After I go home from work, I'll try to rewrite my code. If I have any further questions, I'll leave a comment under this. 
Thanks Graham!!!

Comment: I was able to use city Id to retrieve all 3 data. Thanks !!! From now on I should have more close look to api specs